# Angular in Docker is not exposing the port correctly

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:12.7-alpine AS serve

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["ng", "serve", "--port=81"]
```

Commands

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.dev -t angular-app
docker run -d -p 81:81 angular-app
```

Comment: Missing to expose port : EXPOSE 81

Comment: What do you mean by exposing the port? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the EXPOSE command

try adding this above your `CMD` line.

```
EXPOSE 81
```

Additionally, you may want to use `CMD["npm", "start"]` instead.

EDIT: Nope, ignore this. As @shashankV mentioned, expose is only for documentation purposes.

Comment: Not sure about the `CMD["npm", "start"]` part since Angular uses port 4200 by default.

Comment: you can just set the start script to "ng serve --port=81" instead. Either way doesn't matter. the important thing is the `EXPOSE 81` line.

Comment: Expose is for documentational purposes only, it does not "expose" anything.

Comment: yes you are right. Lord o' mighty. I wish i found out about this earlier

Answer (score 0):

You app might be bound to `localhost` address inside the container. If so it won't be accessible from the outside. Change the address to `0.0.0.0`.

The other answers about `EXPOSE` are incorrect. `EXPOSE` does nothing other than serving as a documentation.